# Graphical glitch in nautilus when dragging icons

Tags: unity, graphics, nautilus

I've looked around on the internet for similar issues, but haven't found anything. This is an issue that affects both my laptop and desktop (both on Ubuntu 17.04). The glitch is that when I drag a file, the effect doesn't display properly and the image of the icon I'm dragging that moves with my mouse is somewhat distorted.[image]

You can see that the icon is what I would describe as clipped and also lacks transparency and blocks out the icons behind it. My laptop has a near-fresh install with only a few non-default programs installed. Any and all help is appreciated.

---

**Input from [r2rx](https://askubuntu.com/users/681160/r2rx) with similar issue:**

I can confirm the same issue (on Ubuntu 17.04 x64).

Here's the result from the `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` command (as suggested by Pilot6):

```
0b:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK110 [GeForce GTX 780] (rev a1)  Subsystem: Device 196e:104b     Kernel driver in use: nvidia    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_381, nvidia_381_drm
```

Currently using the NVIDIA 381.09 driver.

The bug affects text selection and dragging as well:
[Firefox screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjknA.jpg)

Comment: I can confirm that this is an issue with my compiz configuration. I do not see this glitch in xfce

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: I've filed a bug report for this issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/1699731